# What is the most efficient way to setup a DataFrame with hundreds of when statements chained together?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a DataFrame that I need to append a column to using `withColumn`. The `when` conditions for this column number in the multiple hundreds, which is causing a `StackOverflowError` when running the job in `Spark` / `Dataproc`.

Here's the function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

def substitute_in_column(df, cfg):
    for k, v in cfg.items():
        new_column = None
        for index, val in enumerate(v["values"]): <-- v["values"] contains over 500 items
            if index == 0:
                new_column = when(
                    build_when_condition(val["from"]), val["to"])
            else:
                new_column = new_column.when(
                    build_when_condition(val["from"]), val["to"])
        df = df.withColumn(k, new_column)
    return df
```

`build_when_condition` is essentially changing the value of a given column to `val["to"]` based on the logic contained in `val["from"]`.

I am aware of [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SPARK-28742) reported on the Spark Jira board, which may explain the `StackOverflowError`. I'm wondering if there's a different way to achieve the same end that a) is more efficient, and/or b) gets around this bug in Spark.

Comment: aren't you basicly trying to map your values through a dictionary?

Comment: I suppose that's right. If a value meets any one of hundreds of conditions, change the value.

Comment: instead of the above approach, try to create expressions and use that inside select statement.